# use quickly to make a config folder in home

Tags: python, canonical-quickly

I need to make a ~/folder/configFile to use with my aplication. when the deb package is created by "quickly" should create this folder with this file. Someone can teach me to do it?
By the way, can also tell me where should I put my axillary files ".py" in the project folders (like classes and stuff)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [homepath](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html?highlight=homepath) in the docs. You can put your axillary files in the same folder as your application's or in a subdirectory and make them part of [packages](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-installing-package-data).

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to "quickly" when generating the package, create this folder with that file. Independently of the language.

Comment: You can create a package subdirectory and file any way you wish. The `__init__.py` is often empty and even when it is not, it's just a plain text file like any Python script.